# Gauss hypergeometric function at z=-1

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

is there anything like a special value case of the hypergeometric function if $z=-1$ such that one can evaluate $_2F_1(\alpha,\beta; \gamma; -1)$? I mean there is a nice representation for the case that we have $z=1$, but $z=-1$ seems to be a little bit problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case $z=-1$ is **not** problematic, you can simply use e.g. the linear transformations

$$_2F_1\left( a,b;c;z \right)
= (1-z)^{-a} \,_2F_1\left(a,c-b;c;\frac{z}{z-1}\right)
= (1-z)^{-b} \,_2F_1\left(c-a,b;c;\frac{z}{z-1}\right)
$$

and get

$$_2F_1\left( a,b;c;-1 \right)
= 2^{-a} \, _2F_1\left(a,c-b;c;\frac{1}{2}\right)
= 2^{-b} \,_2F_1\left(c-a,b;c;\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
And here a numerical example: $\quad _2F_1\left( 2,-5;1;-1 \right) = 112, \quad
_2F_1\left( 2,6;1;1/2 \right) = 448,$ as you can see they relatated by $\frac{1}{4} = 2^{-a}.$

Answer (score 1):

The existence of nice formulas for the special case $z=1$ is due to the integral representation

$${}_2 F_1  \left( a,b; c ; z\right) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)}\int^1_0 t^{b-1}(1-t)^{c-b-1} (1-zt)^{-a} \, dt$$

The case $z=1$ reduces the formula to a beta integral which is solvable .

In the case $z=-1$ we can have general formulas only for some special cases due to kummer which is called [Kummer's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KummersTheorem.html) .

Comment: I see, but these cases do not apply to what I want to do. Is there no general representation of this function that also applies to the case $z=-1$?

Comment: @lipschitz , no .

Comment: so it is impossible to get the value of this function for $z=-1$. This is hard to believe, but thanks.

Comment: No, it is **not impossible** see my answer! It is only the case that there is no **single** general closed formula in terms of $\Gamma$ or $\Psi$ functions.

Comment: @gammatester , I think the OP is looking for that single general closed form .